# Is there any way to inherit an alias template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template base class:

```
template<class EntityManager>
class System {
public:
  virtual void Update(EntityManager& entity_manager, double dt) = 0;
protected:
  template<typename T> using Component = typename EntityManager::template Component<T>;
};
```

I'd like to use `Component<T>` in my derived template classes.

I've tried to instead have `System` declare `Component` as its own class, but when I try to reference it, the compiler returns, `'Component' was not declared in this scope.`

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
Inteded Usage:

```
template class<typename EntityManager>
class MovementSystem : public System<EntityManager> {
public:
  virtual void Update(EntityManager& entity_manager, double dt) {
    Component<Position> position_component; // I'd like to use Component<T> here.
  }
};
```

Comment: Base classes that depend on a template parameter are not searched when looking up an unqualified-id like `Component`. So, `Component` is inherited, but it's not visible with the usual unqualified lookup in a derived class template specialization. (It might therefore be useful if you include the definition of your derived class.)

Comment: Just a thing to keep in mind. *In general*, you *probably* *could* end up with a better design of ECBS by templating *systems* on *component* types themselves and eliminating `EntityManager` (and any other [class with "manager" in it's name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)) whatsoever. This is not answering your question directly, but could lead to elimination of redundant stuff which would finally solve *the main problem* in a simpler and more pleasant way. Unfortunately, we can't be sure here as we don't know exact problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a derived class template (which is most probably what you mean) you can do

```
using Component = typename System<T>::Component;
```

where `T` is some appropriate type in the derived class.

---

Dealing with a template you can do this:

```
template< class U > using Component = typename System<T>::template Component<U>;
```

as noted by dyp in a comment.

Details depend a bit on the context, here's a [concrete example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd1b240e0ec1d204) for your code given in edit of the post:

```
class ET
{
public:
    template< class Type >
    struct Component {};
};

template<class EntityManager>
class System {
public:
  virtual void Update(EntityManager& entity_manager, double dt) = 0;
protected:
  template<typename T> using Component = typename EntityManager::template Component<T>;
};

template< class EntityManager >
class MovementSystem : public System<EntityManager> {
public:
#ifndef DONTFIXIT
  template< class T > using Component = typename EntityManager::template Component< T >;
#endif

  virtual void Update(EntityManager& entity_manager, double dt) {
    Component<int> position_component; // I'd like to use Component<T> here.
  }
};

auto main() -> int
{
    MovementSystem< ET > ms;
}
```

---

There's no easy way to do this, sorry.

This is clearly an area where the core language has the potential to much better support the programmer, avoiding restating a name over and over again.

---

The rationale for the language being as it is, is that some specializations of `System` may not necessarily define a `Component` type, or an accessible one.

With the `using` you enable the compiler to diagnose lack of such a type, up front.

Comment: *"The rationale for the language being as it is, is that some specializations of System may not necessarily define a Component type, or an accessible one."* [Here's an example of the problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef3b3a577caa66ae)

Comment: Why is it that doing something like `template<typename T> struct Component : public EntityManager::template Component<T> {}` in the base class yields the same result?

Comment: @CharlesW: possibly you haven't instantiated the derived class (you get more checking with an instance). Or possibly you're using Visual C++, which doesn't implement two-phase lookup correctly.

Comment: Not sure why this got upvotes and all before it was correct. Hm.

Comment: It seems odd that the best current solution is to declare the template alias in each derived template class...

Comment: @CharlesW It is possible to use an alias template at namespace scope, similarly to type traits. For example, at namespace scope, `template<typename C, typename T> using Component = typename C::template Component<T>;`